# Calling a Specific Web Service Method Using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, web-services

I've successfully invoked a web service when loading a jsp page. The issue I'm facing is setting up a user to be able to press a button to invoke a different method on that same web service. The function "getSS()" is supposed to accomplish this, but I suppose that javascript doesn't directly read that type of invocation. I've found solutions that call up the web service and pass a parameter to it, but those are usually not calling up specific methods within the webservice.

Here is my code, what can I put in the "getSS()" function to accomplish this? I've already loaded jQuery, and the web service is written in java. Note, I already wrote the code to do all the work, I just need to know how to call that specific code. None of the other solutions seem to fit my needs.

```
<%-- 
Document   : index
Created on : May 6, 2016, 9:39:44 AM
Author     : mmarino
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        function getSS(){
    var e = document.getElementById("names");
    var daString = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    try {
org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS_Service service = new org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS_Service();
org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS port = service.getCalculatorWSPort();
// TODO process result here
java.lang.String result = port.SS(daString);
document.getElementById('inputhere').innerHTML = "hi";
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
    document.getElementById('inputhere').innerHTML = ex;
}
    }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>    <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
    <button value="hi" onclick="getSS()"> Click</button>
    <select id="names">
<%
try {
org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS_Service service = new org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS_Service();
org.me.calculator.CalculatorWS port = service.getCalculatorWSPort();
// TODO process result here

java.lang.String result = port.getNames();
out.println(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%>
    </select>
<hr/>
<div id="inputhere">Hi.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seemed all I was missing was setting that java code to a variable and putting the proper opening and closing statements:

```
  function doIt(){
<%-- start web service invocation --%>
          var x = <%
try {
org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS_Service service = new     org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS_Service();
org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS port = service.getTestBillingWSPort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
java.lang.String name = "Marcel" ;
// TODO process result here
java.lang.String result = port.getSS(name);
out.println(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%>

    alert(x);
        }
    </script>
```

Still not quite sure how to make that "java.lang.String name =" be set to a javascript variable.